# Bootstrap Modal in image not working in iOS

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm having issues with the bootstrap modal not performing as it should on Safari and iOS. I've read similar issues in Stack Overflow, but couldn't find one with a problem using Modals in an image. Can somebody provide some insight and help please?

```
<img alt="therapist" class="img-circle" data-target="#linda" data-toggle="modal" src="img/team/linda.png"> // modal opens when image is clicked
<h3 class="team--name" data-target="#linda" data-toggle="modal">Linda</h3>
<!-- Modal -->
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="linda" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title team--name" id="myModalLabel">Linda</h2>
                <h4 class="team--name">CAMTC</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Linda brings compassion, positive energy and balance into her clients' lives</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried implementing the class below inside the image with no avail.

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Case fixed.

I've added the following script to append modal to body.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal").appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: Did this work because the modal needs to outside the main body?